# How to share constants and variables between files in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

How do you share variables in Swift between files in a **simple traditional way**? I am aware of accessor methods -

**Accessor Example**

```
   SomeOtherClass.getMyVar()
```

But I am looking for just

**Desired Use**

```
    myVar
```

**Context**

So equivalent to how this works in C, with Header Files & #import... Is this possible?

Comment: You may use global variables. Buy you should think twice before using such patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing something is not necessary in Swift.

You have two options (both declared outside any class) :

- A global variable

  ```
  let kNAME_KEY = "name"
  let kAGE_KEY = "age
  ```

  to be called with

  ```
  let name = kNAME_KEY
  ```
- A static variable embedded in a struct

  ```
  struct Key {
   static let Name = "name"
   static let Age = "age"
  }
  ```

  to be called with

  ```
  let name = Key.Name
  ```

The design of Swift highly recommends the way using a struct.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it, but to answer your question you could do the following:

```
class Foo {

    class var Test: String {
        return "MyString"
    }

}

class Bar {

    func someFunc(){
        print(Foo.Test)
    }

}
```

I'm sure someone will come along and give better examples, until then.. here you go :)

Answer (score 1):

katleta3000 was correct. Hard to believe as a 'traditional' C-developer, but correct. Just define a var in a file outside of any other scope (e.g. in a class), and you can magically access it ANYWHERE.

**Example**

- "var someVar = 1" in *ViewController.Swift* on Line 11, above the Line 13 of *'class ViewController: UIViewController {'*
- And now you can use *someVar* in any file within the project, e.g. use in *AppDelegate.swift* is fine

(Context) As a traditionalist, I cry inside at this...

Comment: I'm looking at this, and I'm wondering at the why cry? Instead of having trouble sending information back and forth between multiple ViewControllers, to me, this seems like a genuinely good ide to do? @J-Dizzle

Answer (score 1):

What I did in my Swift project 
1: Create new Swift File
2: Create a struct and static constant in it.
3: For Using just use YourStructName.baseURL

Note: After Creating initialisation takes little time so it will show in other viewcontrollers after 2-5 seconds.

```
import Foundation

struct YourStructName {
        static let MerchantID = "XXX"
        static let MerchantUsername = "XXXXX"
        static let ImageBaseURL = "XXXXXXX"
        static let baseURL = "XXXXXXX"
        }
```